# CompletableFuture thenCompose V.S. thenComposeAsync

Tags: java, asynchronous, completable-future

Based on different posts and articles, all I have known is that: **thenCompose** will run in the same thread with the previous stage while **thenComposeAsync** will try to start a new thread compared to the previous stage.

Even **Java 8 in Action** provides the following code to demonstrate that **thenCompose** will work in the **same thread**.

> Quote from **Java 8 in Action Chapter 11.4.3**

```
public List<String> findPrices(String product) {
    List<CompletableFuture<String>> priceFutures =
        shops.stream()
             .map(shop -> CompletableFuture.supplyAsync(    
                              () -> shop.getPrice(product), executor))
             .map(future -> future.thenApply(Quote::parse)) 
             .map(future -> future.thenCompose(quote -> 
                         CompletableFuture.supplyAsync(
                           () -> Discount.applyDiscount(quote), executor)))
                .collect(toList());

    return priceFutures.stream()
            .map(CompletableFuture::join)   
            .collect(toList());
}
```

But I tried the following code, the result quite confused me which seems quite **opposite** that the **thenCompose** will start new thread while **thenComposeAsync** will reuse the old thread.

```
    public static void main(String... args) {
        testBasic();
        testAsync();
    }
    private static void testBasic() {
        out.println("*****************************************");
        out.println("********** TESTING thenCompose **********");
        ExecutorService executorService = Executors.newCachedThreadPool();
        CompletableFuture[] futures = Stream.iterate(0, i -> i+1)
                .limit(3)
                .map(i -> CompletableFuture.supplyAsync(() -> runStage1(i), executorService))
                .map(future -> future.thenCompose(i -> CompletableFuture.supplyAsync(() -> runStage2(i), executorService)))
                .map(f -> f.thenAccept(out::println))
                .toArray(size -> new CompletableFuture[size]);
        CompletableFuture.allOf(futures).join();
    }

    private static void testAsync() {
        out.println("*****************************************");
        out.println("******* TESTING thenComposeAsync ********");
        ExecutorService executorService = Executors.newCachedThreadPool();
        CompletableFuture[] futures = Stream.iterate(0, i -> i+1)
                .limit(3)
                .map(i -> CompletableFuture.supplyAsync(() -> runStage1(i), executorService))
                .map(future -> future.thenComposeAsync(i ->
                        CompletableFuture.supplyAsync(() -> runStage2(i), executorService)))
                .map(f -> f.thenAccept(out::println))
                .toArray(size -> new CompletableFuture[size]);
        CompletableFuture.allOf(futures).join();
    }

    private static Integer runStage1(int a) {
        String s = String.format("Start: stage - 1 - value: %d - thread name: %s",
                a, Thread.currentThread().getName());
        out.println(s);
        Long start = System.currentTimeMillis();
        try {
            Thread.sleep(1500 + Math.abs(new Random().nextInt()) % 1000);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        s = String.format("Finish: stage - 1 - value: %d - thread name: %s - time cost: %d",
                a, Thread.currentThread().getName(), (System.currentTimeMillis() - start));
        out.println(s);
        return Integer.valueOf(a % 3);
    }

    private static Integer runStage2(int b) {
        String s = String.format("Start: stage - 2 - value: %d - thread name: %s",
                b, Thread.currentThread().getName());
        out.println(s);
        Long start = System.currentTimeMillis();
        try {
            Thread.sleep(200 + Math.abs(new Random().nextInt()) % 1000);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        s = String.format("Finish: stage - 2 - value: %d - thread name: %s - time cost: %d",
                b, Thread.currentThread().getName(), (System.currentTimeMillis() - start));
        out.println(s);
        return Integer.valueOf(b);
    }
```

And the result is as follows:

```
*****************************************
********** TESTING thenCompose **********
Start: stage - 1 - value: 1 - thread name: pool-1-thread-2
Start: stage - 1 - value: 0 - thread name: pool-1-thread-1
Start: stage - 1 - value: 2 - thread name: pool-1-thread-3
Finish: stage - 1 - value: 1 - thread name: pool-1-thread-2 - time cost: 1571
Start: stage - 2 - value: 1 - thread name: pool-1-thread-4  // using a new thread?????
Finish: stage - 1 - value: 2 - thread name: pool-1-thread-3 - time cost: 1875
Start: stage - 2 - value: 2 - thread name: pool-1-thread-2
Finish: stage - 1 - value: 0 - thread name: pool-1-thread-1 - time cost: 2198
Start: stage - 2 - value: 0 - thread name: pool-1-thread-3
Finish: stage - 2 - value: 2 - thread name: pool-1-thread-2 - time cost: 442
2
Finish: stage - 2 - value: 1 - thread name: pool-1-thread-4 - time cost: 779
1
Finish: stage - 2 - value: 0 - thread name: pool-1-thread-3 - time cost: 1157
0
*****************************************
******* TESTING thenComposeAsync ********
Start: stage - 1 - value: 0 - thread name: pool-2-thread-1 // all in same thread
Start: stage - 1 - value: 1 - thread name: pool-2-thread-2
Start: stage - 1 - value: 2 - thread name: pool-2-thread-3
Finish: stage - 1 - value: 0 - thread name: pool-2-thread-1 - time cost: 1623
Start: stage - 2 - value: 0 - thread name: pool-2-thread-1
Finish: stage - 1 - value: 1 - thread name: pool-2-thread-2 - time cost: 1921
Start: stage - 2 - value: 1 - thread name: pool-2-thread-2
Finish: stage - 1 - value: 2 - thread name: pool-2-thread-3 - time cost: 1932
Start: stage - 2 - value: 2 - thread name: pool-2-thread-3
Finish: stage - 2 - value: 0 - thread name: pool-2-thread-1 - time cost: 950
0
Finish: stage - 2 - value: 2 - thread name: pool-2-thread-3 - time cost: 678
2
Finish: stage - 2 - value: 1 - thread name: pool-2-thread-2 - time cost: 956
1
```

Is there something wrong in the demo? Please correct me or if there are some useful resources, do please share.

Comment: your test is too complicated. Don't use stream operators, make it as simple as possible. This requirement is applicable for any test which tries to demonstrate a bug.

Comment: @Alexei I tried, but I have to use **several** loops to make it obvious, otherwise it might fail to happen and to reduce that complexity you mentioned, I tried to use **3** loops only. It's **nested CompletableFuture** usage as that in **Java 8 in Action**.

Comment: @Alexei And also to make it as much as obvious, I tried to use different **thread pool** to make the result easier to understand. Is  there any advice to make it **simpler**? (it's not an easy case for me, which I can simplify further).

Comment: what is your ultimate goal? to control on which thread this or that CompletableFuture instance executes? Actually, this question has little sense. 
You want to find a bug in Java implementation? No way. The Java test base is being developed more than 20 years and covers every imaginable assertion from the language, JVM and library specifications. Thrust them.
There are many more important questions, especially in such spectacular area as parallel and asynchronous programming..

Comment: @Alexei Thanks for the reply. I was wondering what's the **big difference** between them since lots of posts and articles are pointing out the **executing thread difference**. But weird thing is I found out in local tests that the actual case is **not** the same as I read, so I thought I must have missed out something important that I do not know. So I posted this question here. All I wanna achieve is to understand basically: 1. what's going on, why my test is not as they said (even in java 8 in action) and 2. what's the **big difference** really between them.

Comment: there is no big difference. The only difference is the difference in overall execution time - which can be noticeable, and may be not. And not always execution on dedicated thread pool (methods with Async suffix) is faster than on the same thread.